# Is the Glassfish e-mail service a good choice?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, glassfish-3

I have gotten to the point in my application where I want to send e-mail from it.  I found this [web page that](http://www.hildeberto.com/2010/02/sending-e-mails-with-javamail-on.html) describes how GlassFish has a facility where you can let the container handle everything for you.

Alternatively, I can code my own **Thread** that takes jobs from a **BlockingQueue** and constructs and its own **javax.mail.Session** object.  I have actually already done this and it seems to work.   It is really not that much more complicated and I have combined all the **javax.mail.** imports to just one class.

The question is this:  do I get any worthwhile advantage by using the GlassFish service?

The only one I can think of is that GlassFish provides a configuration utility for the e-mail (what server, authentication, etc.).  My web-app already has that ability for the admin user, so that isn't a big deal for me.

Beyond that if I use it, does my application become wired into GlassFish so I have porting problems to other containers if I ever have the need?

Much thanks to anyone who has been there who can share their experience.

Answer (score 2):

This basically isn't about good or bad choices. The javax.mail stuff is build in and provides everything you need for handling mails.
If you play around with Thread and BlockingQueue in any application server you would end up having to use a JCA because everything else would break the java ee spec. So, running this on an application server using the provided mail facilities always is the right choice. 
As far as I know there is no magic involved with javax.mail and the integration with GlassFish. Nothing against using it ...